# Custom keyboard shortcut for changing keyboard layout

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I typically work on Linux machines which have a fairly handy way of changing the keyboard layout with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. On Windows, though it's possible to change the layout with keystrokes, it doesn't seem possible to use this specific keystroke:

[image]

Is there a tool or a registry hack to enable me to customize a shortcut for switching keyboard layouts in Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, the dialog above is what shows up when you try what's recommended there. I'd like the key sequence to be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, and as you can see, it's not one of the options.

Comment: You can use Autohotkey to re-assign the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Use autohotkey and this simple script:
`+{CapsLock}:: Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift}{Ctrl Up}`
This script will send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in background when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. You can refer autohotkey documentation to change this shortcut to whatever you want.